# Jquery animation looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make this animation loop

```
    $(".jquery_bounce").ready(function(){
        $("img", this).animate({ marginLeft : '20px' } , {
                duration: 200,
                complete:function() {
                    $(this).animate({ marginLeft : '0px' } , {
                    duration: 200,
                    easing: 'easeInCubic',
                    }); 
                }
            });
    })
});
    <div class="example">
              <h4>Bounce</h4>
          <div class="jquery_bounce bounce">
            <img src="images/bounceimg.png" class="bounceimg" />
          </div>
    </div>
```

Please help.

Comment: What is the result now? What doesn't work? What should be the outcome?

Comment: Right now it seems to just bounce once then stop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this~

```
  $(function(){
  $.extend({
  show:function(){
   $(".jquery_bounce").ready(function(){
        $("img", this).animate({ marginLeft : '20px' } , {
                duration: 200,
                complete:function() {
                    $(this).animate({ marginLeft : '0px' } , {
                specialEasing: {
                    left: 'swing',
                    top: 'easeOutBounce'
                }
            }); 
                }
            });
    })
  }
});
    setInterval("$.show()",1000);
});
```

***Demo:***

http://jsfiddle.net/VpKw2/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use `setInterval()`?

Edit:

Your animation bounces once, then stops, because...

1. You trigger the margin=20 part.
2. Upon completeness, another animation is scheduled: margin=0.
3. That's it. It doesn't loop because nothing is rescheduled to happen after the first pass.

Read the documentation on `setInterval()`: it's a function that let's you call another function at fixed (in milliseconds) intervals.

If you still want to do it as above, you must fix the problem I pointed out. Try thinking your way around it, and I'll help if you can't figure it out :).

Cheers.

Comment: Can you help me im not sure how i would approach that.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a `bounce` function that will continue the animation, either moving the element left or right:

```
function bounce(elm, leftZero) {
    var px = leftZero ? '0px' : '20px';
    elm.animate({ marginLeft : px}, {
        duration: 200,
        complete:function(){
            //Continue bouncing
            setTimeout(function(){
                bounce(elm, !left);
            },1);
        }
    });
}

$(".jquery_bounce").ready(function(){
        $("img", this).each(function(){
            //Start bouncing
            bounce($(this), false);
        });
    })
});
```